# I have this error and I do not know why: PDOStatement :: execute (): SQLSTATE [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

I am developing a web page with the MVC pattern, I am trying to make a record to my BD, simple record of 2 data. But when doing it, it throws me this error.

Attached my codes if someone could help me I would appreciate it

MODELO:`<?php

require_once "../config/mainModel.php";

class periodosModelo extends mainModel{

```
protected static function agregar_periodos_modelo($datos){


    $sql = mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO año_escolar (periodo_año, periodo_bimestre) VALUES (:periodo_año, :periodo_bimestre)");

    $sql->bindParam(":periodo_año",$datos['periodo_año']);
    $sql->bindParam(":periodo_bimestre",$datos['periodo_bimestre']);

    $sql->execute();
    return $sql;
}
```

}`

CONTROLADOR: `<?php

if ($peticionAjax){

```
require_once "../modelos/periodosModelo.php";
```

} else {

```
require_once "./modelos/periodosModelo.php";
```

}

class periodosControlador extends periodosModelo{

```
public function agregar_periodos_controlador(){

    $periodo_año=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['periodo_año']);
    $periodo_bimestre=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['periodo_bimestre']);

    /*===========Comprobar campos vacios=============*/
    if ($periodo_año=="" || $periodo_bimestre=="") {
        
        $alerta=[

            "Alerta" => "simple",
            "Titulo" => "Ocurrio un error",
            "Texto" => "Llene todos los campos requeridos",
            "Tipo" => "error"

        ];
        echo json_encode($alerta);
        exit();
    }

    /*===========Comprobar grado y seccion existente =============*/

    $check_periodo=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT periodo_año, periodo_bimestre FROM año_escolar WHERE periodo_año='$periodo_año' AND periodo_bimestre='$periodo_bimestre'");

    if ($check_periodo->rowCount()>0) {
        
        $alerta=[

            "Alerta" => "simple",
            "Titulo" => "Ocurrio un error",
            "Texto" => "El periodo escolar ya se encuentran registrado",
            "Tipo" => "error"

        ];
        echo json_encode($alerta);
        exit();

    }
    
    /*===========datos de registro =============*/

        $datos_periodo_reg=[

        "periodo_año"=> $periodo_año,
        "periodo_bimestre"=> $periodo_bimestre

        
    ];

$agregar_periodo=periodosModelo::agregar_periodos_modelo($datos_periodo_reg);

    if($agregar_periodo->rowCount()==1){
        
        $alerta=[

            "Alerta" => "limpiar",
            "Titulo" => "Periodo escolar registrados",
            "Texto" => "El periodo escolar fue registrado correctamente",
            "Tipo" => "success"

        ];

    } else {

        $alerta=[

            "Alerta" => "simple",
            "Titulo" => "Oh no!",
            "Texto" => " ocurrio un error registrando el periodo escolar",
            "Tipo" => "error"

        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($alerta);

}
```

}
`

AJAX: `<?php

$peticionAjax=true;

require_once "../config/APP.php";

if (isset($_POST['periodo_año'])) {

require_once "../controladores/periodosControlador.php";

$insPeriodos = new periodosControlador();

```
if (isset($_POST['periodo_año'])  && isset($_POST['periodo_bimestre'])) {
    
    echo $insPeriodos->agregar_periodos_controlador();
}
```

} else {

```
session_start(['name' => 'SGN']);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ".SERVERURL."login/");
exit();
```

} `

INPUTS DEL FORM: `input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="periodo_año" id="periodo_año" placeholder="Año" required=""  > </div> <div class="col-sm-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="periodo_bimestre" id="periodo_bimestre" placeholder="Periodo"  required=""> </div>`

Comment: Check your sql query, there must be some problem in your bindParam.

Comment: bool PDOStatement::bindParam
( $parameter, $variable, $data_type, $length, $driver_options )